# Showing floating Div instead of dropdownlist's selection item content list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have a dropdownlist for customers in a page . The text field is for customer name and value field is for CustomerID.But selecting customers with the customername is not sufficient enough with this customername, So,instead of this selection content item,I have a floating div which will show the customer full info.

I have done some implementation.When user click on dropdownlist then "onmouseup" events will populate and show the floating div . So, at this moment user will see first dropdwnlist selection item , just below the floating div and page content is under this floating div.

Now , when the floating div will open [visiblity =block] then I want hide the dropdownlist's selection menu list. But I am unable to do this.

Comment: show your code or make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Visibility = block? Aren't you mixing visibility and display properties together? See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp.